# create a htmlhelper to split the text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a field in the table that contains this value "American|African|Asian". I want to get the value form the field and split the text and bind it in the dropdownlist. I am using MVC 3.

So far I have this one:

```
public static SelectList SplitText(this HtmlHelper html, string  texttosplit, string seperator)
{
  return  new SelectList(texttosplit.Split('|'));
}
```

But I don't know how to bind it in the dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_opt1Values, @Html.SplitText(this will have an error it will not accept model => model.EM_opt1Values) )
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is in capital M.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EM_opt1Values, @Html.SplitText(Model.EM_opt1Values))
```

The value should be taken from the `Model` of the page, not from the model variable you define inside the lambda. I can not verify it ATM, but I'm positive this should do it.